# What is the 'attribute error in my code' ? Analyse it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding for to workout this question

**Question**

Using the concept of object oriented programming and inheritance, create a super class named Computer, which has two sub classes named Desktop and Laptop.
Define two methods in the Computer class named getspecs and displayspecs, to get the specifications and display the specifications of the computer.
You can use any specifications which you want.
The Desktop class and the Laptop class should have one specification which is exclusive to them for example laptop can have weight as a special specification.
Make sure that the sub classes have their own methods to get and display their special specification.
Create an object of laptop/ desktop and make sure to call all the methods from the computer class as well as the methods from the own class.

My solution for this is

```
class Computer:

    def __init__(self, ram, gfx, backlit):
        self.ram = ram
        self.gfx = gfx
        self.backlit = backlit

    def getspecs(self):
        self.ram = (input('RAM: '))
        self.gfx = (input('GFX: '))
        self.backlit = (input('Backlit: '))

    def displayspecs(self):
        print('RAM: ', self.ram, 'GFX: ', self.gfx, 'Backlit: ', self.backlit)


class Laptop(Computer):

        def __init__(self, weight):
            self.weight = weight

        def getspecs_laptop(self):
            self.weight = (input('Enter Weight: '))

        def displayspecs_laptop(self):
            print('Weight: ', self.weight)


class Desktop(Computer):

     def __init__(self, size):
         self.size = size

     def getspecs_desktop(self):
         self.size = (input('Enter Size: '))

     def displayspecs_desktop(self):
            print('Size:', self.size)


Computer1 = Laptop
Computer1.getspecs(1)
Computer1.getspecs_laptop(2)
Computer1.displayspecs(3)
Computer1.displayspecs_laptop(5)
Computer1.displayspecs(4)

Computer2 = Desktop
Computer2.getspecs(6)
Computer2.getspecs_desktop(7)
Computer2.displayspecs(9)
Computer2.displayspecs_desktop(99)
```

OUTPUT -

```
"D:\Coding\Python Exercises\Ass6\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Coding/Python Exercises/Ass6/Demo1.py"
RAM: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Coding/Python Exercises/Ass6/Demo1.py", line 43, in <module>
    Computer1.getspecs(1)
  File "D:/Coding/Python Exercises/Ass6/Demo1.py", line 9, in getspecs
    self.ram = (input('RAM: '))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ram'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

1. What is the mistake I am doing?
2. What needs to be given in the parent-thesis in the defined
   objects?

   Computer1.getspecs(here What needs to be added?)

When I run it without giving any value in it, I get error

```
TypeError: getspecs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: You should write a classmethod that gets these values from the user and returns a `laptop` or `Desktop` object.  You should also look into using `super()` to call methods from the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

There are far too many errors in this code to give you a simple answer.  However, I can help with the first few:

1. Most of all, you wrote a lot of code without testing any of it.  As a result, you now have to fix several errors at once to get any useful output.  Comment out your main program for now.  Instead, test your `Computer` class before you try to work with a `Laptop` or `Desktop`.
2. You need to instantiate an object of the class.  *Then* you can use the class methods the way you want.  In particular, `Computer1 = Laptop(3.5)` will give you a `Laptop` object of some weight.
3. Note that each of your `__init__` methods has at least one required argument.  Comment those out until you get used to working with basic objects.

I hope this will allow you to make some progress with your code.